# How to scale server-side Blazor application?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I know that it uses SignalR and requires a consistent connection over the network, and this mean there will be some kind of sticky session problem, which also mean we cannot just scale the deployment like in k8s in a braindead easy way.

I heard that SignalR can be configured to use a Redis backplane, but there doesn't seem to be an easy to do it with ASP.Net core, what steps do I need to do to scale server side Blazor, where the core part is about scaling SignalR? How do we integrate it with cloud native load balancers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Azure SignalR for scaling the connections in Azure. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-5.0) might help you out on this.